# Error in Surv("Time to LTFU", censored) : Time variable is not numeric

Tags: r, numeric, survival-analysis

I am attempting to do a survival analysis, with "time to loss to follow up".
I have tried to fix the error by ensuring that the column is numeric (see strings as factors and colClasses in the .csv read function below), but it has not solved the error.
I have trawled stack overflow and other sites for answers, but I am stuck.
Can anyone help, please?

`````
    library(tidyverse)
    library(gtsummary)
    library(data.table)
    library(tidyr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(survival)
    
    survdat <- fread("221121_HBV_Followup_survivalanalysis.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                     colClasses = c("Time to LTFU"="numeric"))
    
    #Create censoring variable (right censoring)
    survdat$censored[survdat$`LTFU confirmed` == 'Yes']<- 1
    survdat$censored[survdat$`LTFU confirmed` == 'No'] <-0
    
    
    #specify KM analysis model
    km1 <- survfit(Surv('Time to LTFU', censored) ~ 1,
                   data=survdat,
                   type="kaplan-meier")

#I get the following error
> km1 <- survfit(Surv('Time to LTFU', censored) ~ 1,
+                data=survdat,
+                type="kaplan-meier")
Error in Surv("Time to LTFU", censored) : Time variable is not numeric


    
    str(survdat)
    
    
    ````
    NB Have removed some of the variables for confidentiality  
    Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  43 obs. of  10 variables:
     $ Date screened                 : chr  "19/10/2021" "07/07/2021" "18/01/2022" "07/05/2021" ...  
     $ Last date seen                : chr  "21/11/2022" "21/11/2022" "21/11/2022" "21/11/2022" ...  
     $ Time to LTFU                  : num  398 502 307 563 564 605 516 29 118 118 ...  
     $ LTFU confirmed                : chr  "No" "No" "No" "No" ...  
     $ censored                      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
`````

As you can see, the "Time to LTFU" variable IS numeric!

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Time to LTFU` needs to be between backticks, not single quotes, otherwise you are supplying a string (character variable) to the function.

```
km1 <- survfit(Surv(`Time to LTFU`, censored) ~ 1,
               data=survdat,
               type="kaplan-meier")
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Glad it was a simple solution.